# How do I bypass login or Login while testing secure API's in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

How do I bypass login while testing secure API's in django? Currenlty I am trying to login but getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: could you please share your Token model ?

Comment: Its imported from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token. Here. https://ctxt.io/2/AABg5ij-Fw

Comment: I added rest_framework.authtoken in INSTALLED_APPS but it did not work.

Comment: have you run python manage.py makemigrations and migrate ?

Comment: Yes, But no migration was added/run after that. https://ctxt.io/2/AABgWd1kFg

Comment: from the documentation they said that after you add rest_framework.authtoken in INSTALLED_APPS you have to run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes, I did that but had the same problem. https://ctxt.io/2/AABgWd1kFg

Comment: Can you add simple code that just needs to contain the structure of imported modules and classes?

Comment: Here is the tests.py file. You can see the imported modules from there, none of them is a custom module. https://ctxt.io/2/AABgWQMQFg

Comment: could share your settings.py ?

Comment: Sure, Here it is: https://ctxt.io/2/AABguf40FA

Comment: you add `"rest_framework"`  in installed_apps but not `rest_framework.authtoken` that is the problem i think.add  `rest_framework.authtoken`  to your installed_apps and run `python manage.py migrate`.remove it from the middleware it should not be there.

Comment: @ShahZaiƞ I reproduced your problem and when I added `rest_framework.authtoken` to `INSTALLED_APPS` it worked fine. Looking at the code you provided, you added it to `MIDDLEWARE`.

Comment: Yes! My bad! Thank you so much. Got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Add `rest_framework.authtoken` to your INSTALLED_APPS
2. run `python manage.py migrate`

in your case it is not working because you add it inside the MIDDLEWARE.

Comment: Thanks! I added in installed apps and its working now.